# CSS3 transition for horizontal shift caused by center align

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a bar made up of 5 center aligned boxes (images):

```
.boxes {
display:inline-block;
text-align: center;
}
```

When these boxes are clicked, the display is changed to none (through a simple js style change), and the rest of the boxes shift horizontally towards the middle due to the center alignment.
I want to have a CSS3 transition for this movement - something like this

```
    transition: translate 1s linear;
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Could you create a JSFiddle so other people can help you out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text-align` is not one of the [animatable CSS properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-css). So no, you cannot tranisition `text-align`.

To accomplish what you want, you'd most likely have to absolutely position each of the boxes, calculate their positions with JS when they're next to eachother, and then calculate their positions for when one of the boxes is removed.
You could then transition the boxes by changing their `left` and `right` properties, which are animatable.